# Any way to install VS 2013 without IE 11?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to install **VS2013** but it won't be installed without having **IE 11** installed .

IE 11 from some weird reason refuses to be installed .

[image]

Is there any way to install VS 2013 without having IE 11 also installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution :

[Change the registery](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/10/23/fake-ie10-to-install-visual-studio-2013/)

Click `run-->regedit`

Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer`

Change the value of `svcVersion` to `10` , and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

(This should be added comment to the question, but I don't have enough reputation points)
I currently have VS 2013 with just IE 10 and it works fine. Do you have the latest VS 2013 ISOs? The reason I ask is that the requirement for [IE 11 was removed in one of the updates to VS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4153040-remove-the-requirment-for-internet-explorer-10-to).